# Create NULL list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I want to create a list (size 12) of lists (size 2) with NULL entries so I can fill them with the outcomes of a triple loop.
I have tried something like **pred_SAM**:

```
pred_SAM <- list(list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()), list(list()))
```

However I look for something like **pred_SAM_simple** (NULL entries) but with two lists within each of the twelve (containing NULL entries all of them)

```
pred_SAM_simple <- vector(mode = "list", length = 12)
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `rep`

```
out <- replicate(12, rep(list(NULL), 2), simplify = FALSE)
```

check the `str`

```
str(out)
List of 12
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, Akrun!